# Ruby on Rails Enum fetch

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a enum and two Constant

```
  enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1 }

  I_CODE = 23
  J_CODE = 24
```

I have a method in that I have to check status is draft then in database I have to save value 23 and if status is published I have to save 24 in database. when I am trying to compare like status == draft? then it is not working.

```
  def status=(status)
   self[:status] =
   if status.blank?
     nil
   elsif status == 0
     I_CODE
   elsif status == 1
     M_CODE
   end
 end
```

But for showing in UI I want to show if status == draft then it should show draft.

```
def status
  if status == 0
    Draft
  elsif status == 1
    Published
  else
    "----"
  end
end
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. If the status is "draft", then **do you want this to be represented by the value `0`, or the value `23`**? You cannot store two different numbers in the same integer value, and I don't know the significance of this `I_CODE` constant (why does it even matter what integer is used?)

Comment: For example, maybe an idea could be to define: `enum status: { draft: I_CODE, published: J_CODE }`?

Comment: @TomLord, 0 and 1 is coming from different device based on that I need to store value in database for status field as 23 or 24.
Then in UI for reading I need to display as Draft and Published

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest. What do you mean by "coming from a different device", and why does it matter that the value is `23` or `24` in your database? But assuming both of those requirements are legitimate, perhaps you could implement an adapter -- so when the "different device" (??) stores records in your system, you convert the values: `0 --> 23, 1 --> 24`?

Comment: I'm struggling to give a complete answer here, because I think your description only paints an incomplete picture of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this document for [Rails enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), in this case you might want to try:

```
def status
  if draft_status?
    Draft
  elsif published_status?
    Published
  else
    "----"
  end
end
```

But for the method `def status=(status);end`, I suggest modifying the params name to avoid conflict with instance variable status, par example: `def status=(assigned_status);end`. And the comparison should be something like: `assigned_status == self.class.statuses[:draft]`